# How to find the differences between two Array Lists based on a property?

Tags: java, arraylist, find

I have two array list. Each has list of Objects of type Employee.

The Employee class looks like below

```
    public class Employee {

    Employee(String firstname, String lastname, String employeeId) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    private int id; // this is the primary key from employee table

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String employeeId; // manually assigned unique id to each employee

    // getters and setters

}
```

I need to find the differences between the two lists based on a property of the employee object which is employee id.

Employee id is manually generated unique id given to each employee.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class FindDifferences {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<Employee> list1 = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 
        List<Employee> list2 = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 

        list1.add(new Employee("F1", "L1", "EMP01"));
        list1.add(new Employee("F2", "L2", "EMP02"));
        list1.add(new Employee("F3", "L3", "EMP03"));
        list1.add(new Employee("F4", "L4", "EMP04"));
        list1.add(new Employee("F5", "L5", "EMP05"));

        list2.add(new Employee("F1", "L1", "EMP01"));
        list2.add(new Employee("F2", "L2", "EMP02"));
        list2.add(new Employee("F6", "L6", "EMP06"));
        list2.add(new Employee("F7", "L7", "EMP07"));
        list2.add(new Employee("F8", "L8", "EMP08"));

        List<Employee> notPresentInList1 = new ArrayList<Employee>(); 
        // this list should contain EMP06, EMP07 and EMP08

        List<Employee> notPresentInList2= new ArrayList<Employee>(); 
        // this list should contain EMP03, EMP04 and EMP05



    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if your objects are not consistent? For example, if list1 contains ("F1", "L1", "EMPO1") and list2 contains ("F11","L11", "EMP01"). Would that be returned as not in the other list, even though the key is the same?

Comment: @Disco 3. We are just looking for different employee id. In your case they would be viewed as same.

Comment: Your Employee class will need to implement Comparable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods of your `Employee` class to only use `employeeId` when checking for equality (im not sure about why you need the `id` field. you might what to incorporate it as well). NetBeans / Eclipse IDEs can do this for you. Then you can create a **copy** of your original lists and use `List.removeAll()` to calculate difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your lists aren't truly lists, are they? They are really sets of employees without a defined order. They will be easier to compare if they have a defined order. Define a Comparator for employeeId and use Collections.sort to sort the two arrays. Then you need to apply a difference algorithm. I don't see any good generic ones. You could turn your sorted list into XML and then use [XMLUnit's Diff class](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/Diff.html) to get differences. You could render it as a list of strings and apply a [textual diff](http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/). Here is a [discussion](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DiffAlgorithm) on difference algorithms if you want to implement one specific to your use case.

Comment: Isnt there anything the collection framewrok itself which will do this as other are saying to use equalsTo and etc.

Comment: This answer is overkill for your use case. I'm writing a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method removeAll on lists :

```
list1.removeAll(list2);
```

This method will remove the all common elements in list1 and list2 , So after calling this method list1 contains  below employee ids as these are unique from list2
   EMP03
   EMP04
   EMP05

And override the equals method in Employee Class

```
     @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Employee employee = (Employee)obj;

        if ( this.employeeId.equalsIgnoreCase(employee.employeeId)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put both lists of employees into maps instead. The key is `employeeId`. The value is the `employee` object. Then use `removeAll` as @AndrewButenko suggested. You should use maps for more efficient lookups than lists. (Removal involves lookup.) I would recommend set, but then you would need to implement `equals` and `hashcode`. They are already implemented for String.

```
Map<String, Employee> map1 = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
for (Employee e : list1) {
    map1.put(e.getEmployeeId(), e);
}
Map<String, Employee> map2 = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
for (Employee e : list2) {
    map2.put(e.getEmployeeId(), e);
}

// clone makes sure we don't mess with the original map2 because we will reuse it
Collection<Employee> notPresentInList1 = map2.clone().removeAll(map1).values();

Collection<Employee> notPresentInList2 = map1.removeAll(map2).values();
```

If you care about the order of the results, you can either sort the collection at the end or use `TreeMap` instead.