# How to compare a field between two Lists of objects?

Tags: java, list, collections

Let's suppose I've an object that looks like this:

```
public class Supermarket {

    public String supermarketId;
    public String lastItemBoughtId;

    // ...
}
```

and I have two lists of supermarkets, one "old", another "new" (i.e. one is local, the other is retrieved from the cloud).

```
List<Supermarket> local = getFromLocal();
List<Supermarket> cloud = getFromCloud();
```

I would like to find all the pairs of `Supermarket` objects (given `supermarketId`) that have `lastItemBoughtId` different from one another.

The first solution I have in mind is iterating the first `List`, then inside the first iteration iterating the second one, and each time that `local.get(i).supermarketId.equals(cloud.get(j).supermarketId)`, checking if `lastItemBoughtId` of the `i` element is different from the id of the `j` element. If it's different, I add the whole `Supermarket` object on a new list.

To be clearer, something like this:

```
List<Supermarket> difference = new ArrayList<>();
for (Supermarket localSupermarket : local) {
    for (Supermarket cloudSupermarket : cloud) {
        if (localSupermarket.supermarketId.equals(cloudSupermarket.supermarketId) &&
        !localSupermarket.lastItemBoughtId.equals(cloudSupermarket.lastItemBoughtId))
            difference.add(cloudSupermarket);
    }
}
```

Clearly this looks *greatly* inefficient. Is there a better way to handle such a situation?

Comment: Look at this example.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260628/how-to-find-the-differences-between-two-array-lists-based-on-a-property

Comment: Can´t you change the Lists to Maps? This would make it a lot more easy to get the Element with the representing id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution :

1. Construct a Map of the Local supermarkets using the supermarketId as the key by running through the list once
2. Loop through the cloud list and do you comparison, looking up the local supermarket from your map.

i.e. O(n) instead of O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Here's a two-line solution:

```
Map<String, Supermarket> map = getFromLocal().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.supermarketId, s -> s));
List<Supermarket> hasDiffLastItem = getFromCloud().stream()
    .filter(s -> !map.get(s.supermarketId).lastItemBoughtId.equals(s.lastItemBoughtId))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put one of the lists in a `Map` with as key the `Supermarket` ID and as value the supermarket instance then iterate over the other getting from the Map and comparing the `lastItemBoughtId`.